# Nuxt 3 - how to cascade middlewares of parent page to its nested routes

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

version of my nuxtjs: `^3.9.1`

what i want to do:

I have a parent route and some nested children

I would like to implement a middleware on parent so that it runs on children

so I have implemented the middleware in /middleware directory and used `defineNuxtRouteMiddleware` to define it then in parent i used below code:

```
definePageMeta({
  middleware: "x",
});
```

the middleware runs on the parent but not on children.

Comment: Could you plz show your `pages` folder structure which is related to your parent and children routes?